# Where can I get the x, y, z -coordinates for California to use a contour plot?

Tags: gis, plot, modeling

I would like to make California's map by the contour plot. However, I do not know how to get the necessary x, y and z -coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you consulted the [California's Geospatial Information Office](http://gio.resources.ca.gov/)? There's also [geodata.gov](http://geodata.gov/), which links to a bunch of elevation datasets, including the [USGS National Elevation Dataset](http://ned.usgs.gov/).

Answer (score 1):

The GDAL library (www.gdal.org) has many useful commands for processing these types of data.  Most elevation data formats, such as those available through the national map server: 
  http://nationalmap.gov/viewer.html
are readable by GDAL.  The command gdal2xyz.py can read these rasterized files and write X,Y,Z triplets.  Or you can skip straight to rendering contour lines with gdal_contour.  The excellent cross-platform GIS software Quantum GIS (www.qgis.org) is also very useful for processing geospatial data, and includes menu-driven access to most of the functionality of GDAL.