# How can I extract x, y and z coordinates from geographical data by Python?

Tags: python, extract, geography

I have geographical data which has 14 variables. The data is in the following format:

> QUADNAME: rockport_colony_SD      RESOLUTION: 10      ULLAT: 43.625
>   ULLON: -97.87527466      LRLAT: 43.5
>   LRLON: -97.75027466      HDATUM: 27
>   ZMIN: 361.58401489      ZMAX:
>   413.38400269      ZMEAN: 396.1293335      ZSIGMA: 12.36359215      PMETHOD: 5
>   QUADDATE: 20001001

The whole data has many previous variables in the sequence.

How can I extract the coordinates ULLAT, ULLON and LRLAT from the data into three lists, so that the each row corresponds to one location?

This question was raised by the problem in [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486807/where-can-i-get-the-x-y-z-coordinates-for-california-to-use-a-contour-plot).

Comment: Is the data on multiple lines like above or is that a formating issue?

Comment: Instead of three lists, you could use one list of 3-tuples.

Comment: Also, I presume by "LRNAT" you mean "LRLAT".

Comment: Unkwntech: It is a formattindg issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might work if the data is all in a big flat text file:

```
import re

data = """
QUADNAME: rockport_colony_SD RESOLUTION: 10 ULLAT: 43.625
ULLON: -97.87527466 LRLAT: 43.5
LRLON: -97.75027466 HDATUM: 27
ZMIN: 361.58401489 ZMAX: 413.38400269 ZMEAN: 396.1293335 ZSIGMA: 12.36359215 PMETHOD: 5
QUADDATE: 20001001
"""

regex = re.compile(
    r"""ULLAT:\ (?P<ullat>-?[\d.]+).*?
    ULLON:\ (?P<ullon>-?[\d.]+).*?
    LRLAT:\ (?P<lrlat>-?[\d.]+)""", re.DOTALL|re.VERBOSE)

print regex.findall(data) # Yields: [('43.625', '-97.87527466', '43.5')]
```

Comment: @Nick: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment -- are you saying there's something I could make more readable? This was just kind of a proof-of-concept demonstration of how you could use a regex to parse out the data.

Comment: Thank you!

I have your code now in the .py -file. How can I use it to process a .txt -file? 

I guess that we need a parameter in the .py file, so that we can use a syntax like 
$ py-file file-to-be-processed

Comment: @Masi: That sounds like it should be the contents of another question!

Comment: @cdleary: a new post is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491085/how-can-i-use-a-python-file-to-process-a-txt-file

Answer (score 2):

Given a [StreamReader](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#streamreader-objects) named reader, this should give you a list of (float, float, float).  I suggest a list of 3-tuples because it'll probably be more convenient and more efficient to walk through, unless for some reason you only want to get all the points individually.

```
coords = []
reader
while line=reader.readline():

  index_ullat = line.find("ULLAT")
  if index_ullat >= 0:
    ullat = float(line[ index_ULLAT+7 : ])

    line = reader.readline()

    index_ullon = line.find("ULLON")
    index_lrlat = line.find("LRLAT")
    if index_ullon >= 0 and index_lrlat >= 0:
      ullon = float(line[ index_ullon+7 : index_lrlat-1 ])
      lrlat = float(line[ index_lrlat+7 : ])
    else:
      raise InputError, "ULLON and LRLAT didn't follow ULLAT."

    coords.append(ullat, ullon, lrlat)
```

It may work, but it's ugly.  I'm no expert at string parsing.

Comment: Edit: just pointed the link to the new, prettier documentation. :-)