# Extract only numerical data from MATLAB from a text file into a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a code which is producing output files containing information about some mesh which I need to analyse using MATLAB.

The output files look like this.

```
Vertex 1  1.3 -2.1 0 {z=(1.3e+0 -2.1e+0)  mu=(1.4e-3  2.0e-3) uv=(-0.6  0.4)}
Vertex 2  1.4 -2.1 0 {z=(1.4e+0 -2.1e+0)  mu=(2.8e-3  1.5e-3) uv=(-0.6  0.4)}
Vertex 3 -1.9  1.9 0 {z=(-1.9e+0 1.9e+0) mu=(-8.9e-2  1.4e-1) uv=( 0.7 -0.2)}
.
.
.
```

I would like my MATLAB code to read in this data file and form a matrix containing all the numbers 
in the order specified.

So e.g I would want the above 3 lines to be processed into the matrix

```
 1  1.3 -2.1 0 1.3e+0 -2.1e+0  1.4e-3  2.0e-3 -0.6  0.4
 2  1.4 -2.1 0 1.4e+0 -2.1e+0  2.8e-3  1.5e-3 -0.6  0.4
 3 -1.9  1.9 0 -1.9e+0 1.9e+0 -8.9e-2  1.4e-1  0.7 -0.2
```

Is there some convenient MATLAB facility/command to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could use [textscan](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) for this:

Example date.txt:

```
Vertex 1  1.3 -2.1 0 {z=(1.3e+0 -2.1e+0)  mu=(1.4e-3  2.0e-3) uv=(-0.6  0.4)}
Vertex 2  1.4 -2.1 0 {z=(1.4e+0 -2.1e+0)  mu=(2.8e-3  1.5e-3) uv=(-0.6  0.4)}
Vertex 3 -1.9  1.9 0 {z=(-1.9e+0 1.9e+0) mu=(-8.9e-2  1.4e-1) uv=( 0.7 -0.2)}
```

Code:

```
fileID = fopen('data.txt');

C = textscan(fileID,'Vertex %f %f %f %f {z=(%f %f) mu=(%f %f) uv=(%f %f)}');

fclose(fileID);

mtxC = [C{:}];
```

Result:

```
mtxC =

    1.0000    1.3000   -2.1000         0    1.3000   -2.1000    0.0014    0.0020   -0.6000    0.4000
    2.0000    1.4000   -2.1000         0    1.4000   -2.1000    0.0028    0.0015   -0.6000    0.4000
    3.0000   -1.9000    1.9000         0   -1.9000    1.9000   -0.0890    0.1400    0.7000   -0.2000
```

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB Option (partly tested)

I had to do something similar with a CMM once and it was easy to do in Python (see below). You could use the MATLAB command [`regexp(text, expression)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to match a regular expression that gets what you want. This will return string data though, which you can save to a data file and then [load that data file](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/ways-to-import-text-files.html), or convert to numbers using [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html).

To use this, you first have to get your data file into MATLAB as series of strings. You can do this with [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html).

```
in_fid = fopen('my_input_file.txt', 'r');
out_fid = fopen('my_output_file.txt', 'w');
data = [];

line = fgetl(in_fid);
while ischar(line)
    match = regexp(line, '[+-]?\d+\.?\d*e?[+-]?\d*', 'match');  % find all matches

    % Write to text file
    fprintf(out_fid, '%s\t', match);  % write values to file with tabs between
    fprintf(out_fid, '\n');  % write a new line to the file

    % Or save to an array locally
    data = [data; str2double(match)];

    line = fgetl(in_fid);  % grab the next line
end
fclose('all');

% If you wrote to a text file, retrieve the data
data = dlmread('my_output_file.txt', 'delimiter', '\t');  % not sure about this...
```

Note that this will *not* match numbers that begin with a decimal point with no preceding digit, i.e. `.2`. Also note that this will match numbers that match the pattern in any file that you feed it, so it is generalized. For how to match floating point numbers, [see this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html) (I changed it a bit though to add the `e` portion for scientific notation).

I was able to test the `regexp` and `str2double` operations on a remote machine, and it looks like building your data array directly works. I was unable to test the file I/O portion, so there may be some bugs there still.

## Python Option (my favorite)

I suggest using regular expressions in Python for this sort of thing. I had to do something similar with a CMM once and it was easy to do in Python with something like:

```
import re

# Make pattern to match scientific notation numbers
pattern = re.compile(r"[+-]?\d+\.?\d*e?[+-]?\d*")

with open("your_input_file.txt", "r") as in_file:
    with open("your_output_file.txt", "w") as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            match = pattern.findall(line)  # find all matches in the line
            out_file.write("\t".join(match) + "\n")  # write the results to a line in your output
```

For a good introduction to regex in Python, see [Dive Into Python 3](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/regular-expressions.html), which I recommend just about everybody reads. I tested this on your example file and it gives me:

```
1  1.3  -2.1  0  1.3e+0  -2.1e+0  1.4e-3  2.0e-3  -0.6  0.4
2  1.4  -2.1  0  1.4e+0  -2.1e+0  2.8e-3  1.5e-3  -0.6  0.4
3  -1.9  1.9  0  -1.9e+0  1.9e+0  -8.9e-2  1.4e-1  0.7  -0.2
```

in `your_output_file.txt`, so I think it works! The last step then is to just `dlmread('your_output_file.txt', 'delimeter', '\t')` in MATLAB and you should be good to go.

If you want to get fancy, you could upgrade your Python script so that it can be called from the command line with your input and output files as arguments (look into the `sys.argv` method), but this gets a bit more complicated and it is easy enough to just open the script and change the filename manually. Unless you need to do this all the time on differently-named files, in which case arguments are a good route. [There is a good example of this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491085/how-can-i-pass-a-filename-as-a-parameter-into-my-module).

Comment: Normally I would down vote it, as the answer is mostly about python and OP does not ask about python. Otherwise, why not give answer in JavaScript or PHP or Ruby or perl. Please don't do it.

Comment: Python because I have had exactly this problem before and Python was way easier to implement than MATLAB. If somebody offers a better answer that uses MATLAB exclusively then that would be my vote for the "right answer," but this does exactly what OP wants and, imo, is easier to implement.

Comment: But the question is about Matlab: "Is there some convenient MATLAB facility/command to do this?"

Comment: @Marcin Updated with a MATLAB solution that should work as well.